# EF Core: How to best aggregate over related entitiy properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

Let's say I have a list Books and a list BooksRead, where I could track if I have read a book, so I have an Entity "`Book`" and an entity "`BookRead`".

Everytime I assign a BookRead entity to `Book`, I want a counter on Book to increment (property: `TimesRead`).

I have implemented such a scenario in different ways already. One time using a NotMapped property, where I  do something like this:

```
[NotMapped]
int TimesRead => ReadEntries.Count
```

But because I use a component, that cannot sort by a property which is not mapped, I switched it to a property that is mapped. Everytime I now add a BookRead entry, or delete one, I also update the corresponding "`TimesRead`" value.
As there are different places in my applications a user can add such an entry, I had to include this calculation in multiple places, so I wonder if there is better approach.

Also I switched my AverageRating property to mapped, which is even more bothering, as the rating can be set on various pages.

I had a look at calculated columns, but I believe they only work for data that is in the same table.

There is also the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, so I could theoretically work with events. But I'm not to fond of this idea.

What would be a clean approach for this scenario?